# How to I implement Facebook re-authorization in ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, facebook-login

I am using Facebook login SDK for my ios10 app running in iphone 6 . After logging in with my Facebook account. I logged out, but each time I try to login again it authenticate me right away. Can I login with another Facebook account?

How to I implement Facebook re-authorization in ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear your history and website data for safari on the iPhone. Also, make sure that your Facebook account is disconnected in the settings of the iPhone.

Comment: Thanks It worked. I was just disconnecting the Facebook from settings. Clearing the history for safari worked.